# How to open context menu on SublimeText 2 sidebar using keyboard?

Tags: sublimetext2, text-editor, sublimetext

On SublimeText we can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> to move navigation to the sidebar. Is there anyway to open the context menu on items with keyboard like when you right click?

I am on Windows xp and SublimeText 2.0.1

Comment: Didn't know about ctrl+0, cheers... it seems to be special case of ctrl+<num> for jumping between views... I looked at it, didn't find anything... menu-key doesnt work, neither does context_menu command, which is usually mapped on right click in Default.sublime-mousemap. It works when mapped on key shortcut, but only in tab, not in sidebar... that's weird

Answer (score 2):

Is the following what your want? Add the following key mapping. And try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+f", "ctrl+l"], "command": "context_menu" }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think the issue is for some reason, it is not opening the context-menu on the side bar. This works like context_menu key on the keyboard it works on the page itself , but it does not work on the side-bar.

Comment: Yes, it won't works on the side-bar. And I couldn't find a way to open context menu on the side-bar.

Comment: @VladimirStarkov not that I am aware of

Comment: For your information, shift+F10 is the default keyboard shortcut for opening the right-click context menu on Windows (e.g. try it in windows explorer, Word, ...)