# Sublime Text 3 Sidebar Context Menu

Tags: sublimetext2

I wanted to know if there is a mac key binding that would work to show context menu while on the sidebar. I don't want to have to right click all the time to get the context menu and would prefer to have the key binding.

Comment: I am guessing this is a -1 because nobody has an answer for this question. No other reason to give it a -1, unless you are bored

Comment: This question is related : [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972780/how-to-open-context-menu-on-sublimetext-2-sidebar-using-keyboard[/link] no solution for it as of this writing though. :(

Answer (score 1):

**Add a key mapping**. **Sublime Text > Preferences > Key Bindings-User**. For example you could use Ctrl+h (not assigned), syntax is below.

```
[

    { "keys": ["ctrl+h"], "command": "context_menu" }

]
```

Comment: I tried the above but no luck... it can only open the context menu in the main editor windows not but not the one for the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

Add a keybinding by:

`Ctrl + Shift + P` (or `Cmd+Shift+P` on OSX), then type: `Preferences: Key Bindings`,

Then assign `Ctrl + '` (as an example, you can use any key binding) using the following syntax:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+'"], "command": "context_menu" }   
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a MAC related question, than sublime text related. As I don't own a MAC myself, I can only give you some advice:

Question is, what are you trying to achieve with right clicking? There are loads of useful keyboard shortcuts, which basically do the same thing and either exist by default, or can be easily set in the key bindings file manually (if you don't know how, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635417/how-do-i-add-sublime-text-2-keybindings)).

For quick file switching and navigation, I highly recommend you getting used to "Goto Anything" (Command+P). Getting yourself used to this is the hardest part, but once you got used to, you don't want to turn back.

For file and folder creation there are useful plugins which work on command line basis and by far more efficient than clicking, scrolling, searching... just saying.

I also highly recommend [these excellent sublime text tutorials](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/perfect-workflow-in-sublime-text-free-course/) by jeffrey way.

Comment: What I am looking to do is have the same control as I do in WebStorm. If I want to have a key binding that will bring up the context menu for any file on the sidebar, I then can use my arrow keys to do what I need to with the file. I know the rest of the key bindings and have set plenty up, as well as plugins. But none of them give me this option. It would be nice to be able to delete a file for example without having to touch the stupid mouse.